# If Keras is forcing me to use a large batch size for prediction, can I simply fill in a bunch of fake values and only look at the predictions I need

Tags: keras, neural-network, batch-processing

...or is there a way to circumvent this?

In stateful LSTMs, I have to define a batch size but Keras is forcing me to use the same batch size in training as in prediction, but I find that my modeling problem depends a lot on having larger batch sizes to see good performance.

Comment: Keras is nor forcing you anything, these are the limitations of the algorithm you are using (a stateful LSTM), why are you using stateful LSTMs for this problem?

Comment: The sequence is long. Normally about 1,000 timesteps.

Comment: LSTMs can model long sequences, and they don't need to be stateful for that. I am asking specifically about a stateful LSTM, not about a LSTM.

Comment: Also note that it is the stateful flag that requires a fixed training/test batch size.